# c#.net Custom Validation throwing an error when a field is editted correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have the following simple code to check the gender of a member has been entered correctly.

```
public partial class Member
{
    partial void OnGenderChanging(string value)
    {
        if (!((value.ToLower() == "male") || (value.ToLower() == "female")))
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Must be Male or Female.");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm happy with this and it works fine MOST of the time. The custom validation has been added to a table with existing data and it works when adding a new member record and it also prevents you from changing the gender from something acceptable (say female) to something that isn't (e.g. f). However one of the records in the table has a value in it that is incorrect and that was entered BEFORE the validation was added. When I try to edit the record through the edit.aspx page provided by DynamicData so that the gender is 'male' or 'female' it throws the error message...even though the new value is correct.

I know I can edit it directly within the database to solve it but I'd really like to know what's going on in the background. Why does the OnChanging event seem to be looking at the original value in this particular situation rather than the new one?

Any help would be gratefully received please.

Comment: we don't have enough info: who call `OnGenderChanging` and when?

Answer (score 0):

You throwing an exception when the input is match "female" at first. Check your if statement.

Try

```
 public partial class Member
{
    partial void OnGenderChanging(string value)
    {
        if (((value.ToLower() != "male") && (value.ToLower() != "female")))
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Must be Male or Female.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: please note that you need to use AND instead of OR.